# Zero conditional with present continuous

Tags: present-continuous, conditionals

In the following sentence:

> When you build a health clinic, you’re also creating part of the infrastructure for fighting epidemics. (by Bill Gates)

Why is the present continuous used in the second part? Will the meaning be the same with present simple ("you also create...")?

Comment: The present simple states a fact: 'you also create' = the infrastructure is created (and this fact happens always, with certainty, every time)...............................The present continuous makes the statement abstract in the sense that you can choose to accept that the infrastructure is also in place rather than it having a definite physical presence.

Comment: *When you do this, you're also doing that. When you do this, you also do that. When you're doing this, you're also doing that. When you're doing this, you also do that.* All permutations are valid, and I can't see that any of them carry any subtle "semantic nuance" not shared by the others. I would have suggested you should just choose whichever form seems most natural to you, but the reality is most native speakers would use Simple Present throughout, and speakers of "Indian English" might tend to "unnaturally" favour excessive use of the continuous. So I suggest **KISS** (Keep it SIMPLE! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you very much!